# PHP returns correct data, but AJAX/JQuery call does not contain JSON object

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello logical thinkers!!,
    I am trying to return a JSON object from from an array that has been returned from a function call written in PHP.  It was returning the object yesterday, but somehow or another I have managed to break it.  If anyone could please help I would greatly appreciate it.  Below is the code listed from my Javascript and PHP...Thanx again for any help that may be provided.

--PHP--

```
<?php
class FileSel{

public $event;
public $posUsr;
public $posPass;
public $posAddr;
public $scUsr;
public $scPass;
public $scAddr;
public $cclUsr;
public $cclPass;
public $confName;

//Variable used to hold the connection
var $scp;
//Variable used to hold the final list of files to be displayed to the user to choose from
var $List = array();
//Variable used to hold the list of possible SC files
var $SCFiles = array();
//Variable used to hold the list of possible POS files
var $POSFiles = array();
//Variable used to hold the list of possible CCL files
var $CCLFiles = array();

function __construct(){
    $this->debug = new debug();
}

public function execute(){
    $this->debug->putLog("Made it to FileSel->execute()\n");
    return new Response(true, "Build List executed", json_encode($this->buildList()));
}

public function load_post_data(){
    $this->debug->putLog("Made it to FileSel->load_post_data()\n");
    $this->event = $_POST['event'];
    $this->posUsr = $_POST['pos_user'];
    $this->posPass = $_POST['pos_password'];
    $this->posAddr = $_POST['pos_address'];
    $this->scUsr = $_POST['sc_user'];
    $this->scAddr = $_POST['sc_address'];
    $this->cclUsr = $_POST['ccl_user'];
    $this->cclPass = $_POST['ccl_password'];
    $this->confName = $_POST['confName'];

    if( strlen($this->event) <= 0) return false;
    if( strlen($this->posAddr) <= 0) return false;
    if( strlen($this->posUsr) <= 0) return false;
    if( strlen($this->posPass) <= 0) return false;
    if( strlen($this->scAddr) <= 0) return false;
    if( strlen($this->scUsr) <= 0) return false;
    if( strlen($this->scPass) <= 0) return false;
    if( strlen($this->cclUsr) <= 0) return false;
    if( strlen($this->cclPass) <= 0) return false;
    if( strlen($this->confName) <= 0) return false;

    return true;
}

public function buildList(){
    $this->debug->putLog("Made it to FileSel->buildFileArray()\n");    
    //Build a list of files from the POS
    $this->listPOSFiles();
    //Build a list of files from the SC
    $this->listSCFiles();
    //Build a list of files from the CCL
    $this->listCCLFiles();
    $this->debug->putLog("Building final file list\n");
    //Variable used to keep track of index of final list
    $j=0;

    //Here we are adding POS files to the final list
    foreach($this->POSFiles as $file){
        $this->List[$j] = $file;
        $this->debug->putLog("Added POS File: $file to final file list\n");
        $j++;
    }

    //Here we are adding POS files to the final list
    foreach($this->SCFiles as $file){
        $this->List[$j] = $file;
        $this->debug->putLog("Added SC File: $file to final file list\n");
        $j++;
    }

    //Here we are adding POS files to the final list
    foreach($this->CCLFiles as $file){
        $this->List[$j] = $file;
        $this->debug->putLog("Added CCL File: $file to final file list\n");
        $j++;
    }

    return $this->List;
    }
    }

?>
```

--Javascript--

```
function displayDialog(){
    //console.log("Made it to displayDialog");
    var fileData = {
        "event" : "createFileSelectDialog",
        "pos_address" : file_pos_address,
        "confName" : file_confName,
        "pos_user" : file_pos_user,
        "pos_password": file_pos_password,
        "ccl_user" : file_ccl_user,
        "ccl_password": file_ccl_password,
        "sc_address" : file_sc_address,
        "sc_user" : file_sc_user,
        "sc_password": file_sc_password
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: './lib/app.php',
        data:  fileData,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

If there is any other information that I can provide that will help solve this problem, please let me know and I will post it.

Comment: Where do you output your json? And how have you checked whether the output is OK?

Comment: Your PHP needs to `echo` the JSON, not `return` it.

Comment: out of curiosity, what does the "POS" in `POSFiles` stand for? :P

Comment: What is `new Response` and how is `execute()` called?

Comment: We need to see the definition for your Response class. Nothing in your code shows us how the data is being output to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Response class; are you using a framework? If so, I would look at the source code for that to see what happens when it's constructor is called. E.g. does it automatically print the third parameter to output, or do you have to manually print a property or method on the instantiated object, or maybe the output text is returned? Depending on the functionality, it could be as simple as replacing "return new Responce(...)" with "echo new Response(...)".